# Why use article 'the' in phrase The university of Texas at Dallas?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Why use article 'the' in the phrase **The university of Texas at Dallas**?

The founders of UTD named it "The University of Texas at Dallas" while the founders of UF named it "University of Florida". What was the reason the article "the" was used?

Comment: Can you add some information to your question, telling us a little about why you're confused? That will help people write you a better answer. More information is [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/6700).

Comment: Thank you all reviewed my question. I want to explain more my question. The founders of UTD named it was "The University of Texas at Dallas " while the founders of UF named it "University of Florida".What was  reason article " the" used. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your name example

> [The University of Texas at Dallas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Texas_at_Dallas)

"**The**" is used because it is the [*official name*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Texas_System#component_institutions) of **UTD**.

In your specific case, why the *Texas University System* chose to use "**The**" is anyone guess, maybe because they are Texans *loud and proud*.  One notes that in the more *laid back* land of the west coast, the *University of California System* decided not to use "**the**"

> [As of 2016, the following data are taken from List of Nobel laureates by university affiliation and are not the official count from **University of California**.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_California#Nobel_Prize_winners)

And also their campus are *named* "**UC** *something*".

Comment: Wikipedia isn't the best place to get examples of usage, and the University of California is very much *the University of California* even if it isn't *The University of California*.